# Renaming Column with Dynamic Name

Tags: sas

I have a column name from a .xls file (using excelcs engine for importing) which is dynamic and changes from day to day.

I am wondering how to do reference and rename that dynamic column name within sas without knowing before hand what it will be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends some on how it dynamically changes.  If it is entirely unpredictable - you cannot write code to figure it out, or to eliminate the other known columns - your simplest option may be to use `GETNAMES=NO`, and then set the names yourself.

If it is in some way predictable (such as it is "MYDYNAMIC_XXXX" where XXXX changes in some fashion), you can probably figure it out from `dictionary.columns`.  (Modify libname/memname/etc. as appropriate; `memname` is the dataset name.)

```
proc sql;
 select name into :dynname
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname='WORK' and memname='MYDATASET'
    and name like 'MYDYNAMIC_%';
quit;
```

Alternately, you could use a `NOT(IN(...))` clause to eliminate the known column names, if you need to know that.

Finally, if it is in one consistent location, easier than using `GETNAMES=NO` may be to query dictionary.columns based on the variable number (`where varnum=5` for example if it is the fifth variable number).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Joe's last comment - is the column is in the same position, just called something different?

If so, you can use the `dictionary.columns` table, selecting the specific column number, and storing the corresponding column name in a macro variable.

Example, your column is the 5th column in Excel/dataset...

```
/* Pull column name */
proc sql ;
  select name into :DYNVAR
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'SASHELP'
    and memname = 'CLASS'
    and varnum  = 5 ;
quit ;

/* Then to reference the column simply substitute it for &DYNVAR */
data want ;
  set sashelp.class (keep=&DYNVAR) ;
run ;
```

You could then extend this to multiple columns if necessary...

```
/* Pull column name */
proc sql ;
  select name into :DYNVARS separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'SASHELP'
    and memname = 'CLASS'
    and varnum  in (1,4,5) ;
quit ;

/* Then to reference the columns simply substitute it for &DYNVARS */
data want ;
  set sashelp.class (keep=&DYNVARS) ;
run ;
```