# Naming columns using values from data table

Tags: sas

Let's say I have two columns A and B.

```
A     B
12    "randstr"
39    "randstr"
2     "randstr"
```

This random string is repeated in each row.

I'm interested in how I can get the table below:

```
randstr     B
12          "randstr"
39          "randstr"
2           "randstr"
```

The value in the column B was used to rename column A. I have tried using `rename` and all sorts of macro magic but failed. I have no idea how to proceed.

I've tried the answers below and they just don't allow for reading the value from the data and then using the value as a column name:

1. https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/dates-used-as-column-names/td-p/168803
2. https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/code/a-few-sas-macro-programs-for-renaming-variables-dynamically/
3. [SAS - Dynamically create column names using the values from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698919/sas-dynamically-create-column-names-using-the-values-from-another-column/33700159#33700159)
4. [Renaming Column with Dynamic Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768649/renaming-column-with-dynamic-name?rq=1)

Comment: Is this a homework question, this is not the first time today I've seen it/ Anyways, you're looking for how to create a format. Google a paper called: PROC FORMAT not just another pretty face and it has some really good examples.

Comment: If you want actual code help, your question doesn't follow SO rules, you need to show what you've tried, not just say you've tried something.

Comment: @Reeza I'm pretty sure PROC FORMAT won't work. String is random, I cannot list all of the values. I've added 3 answers I've tried. It's also not homework, I'm doing this at work and have just started to play with macros and thought there might be a way.

Could you link me to the question that you've seen repeated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [macro](https://github.com/Boemska/macrocore/blob/master/base/mf_getvalue.sas), it's fairly straightforward:

```
/* get first value in the dataset */
%let new_col=%mf_getvalue(work.YOURDATA,B);

/* rename variable A */
proc datasets library=work nolist;
 modify YOURDATA;
 rename A=%sysfunc(dequote(&new_col));
quit;
```

Comment: Works! Exactly what I've needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The transformation could also be seen as a row-wise transposition.

```
data have;
attrib A length=8 B length=$32;
row+1;
input
A   & B; datalines;
12    xyz-123-abc
39    xyz-123-abc
2     xyz-123-abc
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want(drop=row _name_);
  by row;
  var A;
  id B;
  copy B;
run;
```

In non-toy scenarios the `B` column is often not a single value. Try the same transpose with data having variation in `B`.  The procedure will create two new columns from the values of `B`.

```
A   & B; datalines;
12    xyz-123-abc
39    xyz-123-abc
2     xyz-123-abc
3141  xyz-456-def
```